# How to find a release date of an upcoming point-and-shoot camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I read some reviews about the Canon Powershot S100. It sounds like this camera is perfectly suited for my needs. But unfortunately it is not available yet. I can't find an actual release date, neither on online shops, nor on the [manufacturer's homepage](http://www.canon.de/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_Camera/PowerShot/PowerShot_S100/).

Is there any other source where I can find reliable release dates for cameras? I'm looking for release dates in Switzerland or at least Central Europe.

Comment: Oh, the original [PowerShot S100](http://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/compacts/canon_ixus) is already out of production :) Amazon UK promises the reincarnation for [January 1, 2012](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Canon-PowerShot-S100-Digital-Camera/dp/B005N5NF6I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325291059&sr=8-1).

Comment: Thanks for this comment and the answers so far. I should have added that I'm looking for release dates in Switzerland or at least Central Europe.

Answer (score 3):

The [Canon Powershot S100](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=canon%20s100&N=0&InitialSearch=yes) is available right now. I agree it is an extremely interesting camera.

Release dates are not easy to find because they vary by region. Typically, there
will be a press release announcing the *intended* date approximately, usually something like *End Of November*. At that point stores will *usually* begin to get the model, starting with the bigger stores in major population centers. You can often find press release summaries at [camera](http://blog.neocamera.com/) and [gadgets](http://www.gizmodo.com) sites but your best source is the manufacturer's *News* page. If you are outside of North America, you should look for regional publications. Sometimes a model will not be at all available locally.

*This year has been particularly unlucky because the Japan earthquake and tsunami, followed by floods in Thailand have delayed by several months quite a few cameras announced since the last quarter of 2010.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's my favorite place to find what models are in stock and where:

http://www.nowinstock.net/digitalcameras/canon/pointandshoot/